# change qtextedit text when textChanged()

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I'm creating a qtextedit with syntax highlighting. The method that i'm thingking of is replacing qtextedit text with colored text when textChanged() event occurs. The problem is when i replace text in textChanged() funtion, another textChanged() occurs :(, please help!

Here is my code:

```
def teditSQL_color_text(self):
    text = self.teditSQL.toPlainText()
    text = text.replace('select', '<font color=blue>select</font>')
    self.teditSQL.setText(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are other solutions as well but you can prevent objects from emitting signals by using the `blockSignals` method. So wrap it around your `setText` call like this.

```
def teditSQL_color_text(self):
    text = self.teditSQL.toPlainText()
    text = text.replace('select', '<font color=blue>select</font>')
    wasBlocked = self.teditSQL.blockSignals(True)
    self.teditSQL.setText(text)
    self.teditSQL.blockSignals(wasBlocked)
```

Comment: It's not working bro! still get the error: `Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.`

Comment: I also heard about Qsyntaxhighlighter but i don't know how to implement it! (i'm new)

Comment: Oops, that should be `self.teditSQL.blockSignals`. I will update my answer.

Comment: I always find the examples that come with the PyQt source distribution a good starting point to learn how to use the classes. Download the PyQT source from [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and look at `examples/richtext/syntaxhighlighter.py` to see how the `QSyntaxHighlighter` can be used.